# Check for Windows Updates on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

How do you check for Windows Updates on Windows Server 2008 R2?  I have searched around on the machine and can't find where I run a check.

Comment: If you press F1, it will bring up the help system that will point you to this. Google will too.

Answer (score 7):

Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Update >Check for Updates

OR

Just type "Windows Update" into the search bar in the start menu.

OR as KCotreau pointed out

Start > All Programs > Windows Update

Answer (score 3):

Start>All Programs>Windows Update .

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do this from the command line or from with scripts, the command I use on Server 2003 is `wuauclt /detectnow` and I know of no reason that shouldn't work on 2008.